# specflow generate step definitions missing from context menu

Tags: specflow

I followed the getting started instructions and the "generate step definitions" is missing from context menu.

I tried adding the additional specflow packages from nuget for mstest and still nothing.

Comment: Which Visual Studio Version are you using?

Comment: The free Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: have you also installed the VS extension?

Comment: I used .NET Core with Specflow 2 and had this issue. Specflow 2 is for NET 4.5+ - Specflow 3 will support NetCore/4.7.2

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was looking for this option in contextual menu of the *feature* file, but this option exists in the contextual menu of the **content** of the *feature* file. So, try open the feature file (*.feature) in the Visual Studio text editor and click right button of the mouse **inside text editor**. Example of the file:

```
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are bringing up the correct context menu by right clicking in the .feature file as opposed to anywhere else then you may find that the issue is actually caused by the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll not being referenced in your project.

To add the reference manually (NuGet didn't do it for me) right-click on the References folder of your project and find the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll which will likely be in '[project]/packages/SpecFlow.X.X.X/lib/netXX/' (X's are version numbers).

Here is the context menu when I don't have the correct reference in place:

[image]

And here it is once I do:

[image]

This was SpecFlow.2.1.0 and VS2010 which led me to another issue with incompatible .Net versions so I ended up using SpecFlow.1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `SpecRun.SpecFlow` from the `Nuget` `Packages`, after installation completes you'll get the "Generate Step Definitions" on the context menu.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install specflow from Extensions and updates and then restart the visual studio, clean and rebuild the solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. maybe it was related with fresh IDE installation or maybe it was something new... here is just short note about this issue and possible solution:

1. At the beginning of IDE/project configuration check or install packages for **SpecFlow** in the NuGet manager.
2. Check twice what exactly you will use in the project **Xunit** or **Nunit** and then install the related package **Xunit** or **Nunit**. In my case, I was working with **Xunit** and install it.
   [image: SpecFlow.Xunit_pic]
   [image: instaled packages]
3. After installation, you will see  new items in the References
   [image]

   and pop about re-generation feature files
   [image: re_generating_pop_up]
4. After that **Generation steps** will be available
   [image: generate_step_defenitions_option]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you may not have the simply installing the Extension for SpecFlow at Solution level is not enough.

SpecRun.SpecFlow is an evaluation version unless you are prepared to play for a license key.

I added the NuGet package `SpecFlow.xUnit` to the Unit test Project within my solution where I held my feature files. This resolved the issue, I now see `Generate step definitions`.

This is achieved by Right-clicking on your feature file in the code editor and select Generate Step Definitions from the popup menu. A dialogue is then displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I migrated an existing project to a new PC.

Turns out I need to do: Visual Studio 2019 > Extensions > Manage Extensions > select 'Online' in the left hand nav > then search for 'Specflow' in the search box > then download it and close Visual Studio.  It auto installs then.

Finally reopen VS and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2022 the context menu item "generate step definitions" renamed to "Define steps" as per below specflow documentation.
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/visualstudio/Generating-Skeleton-Code.html